# Can you obtain the probability distribution on a finite discrete space through its moments? If so, how?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, polynomials

Consider a probability distribution on the set of all ordered binary strings of length $M$. Each element may then be written as $( s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_M )$ with each $s_k \in \{ 0, 1\}$ and the probability distribution is a non-negative function $p(\{s_k\})$ which sums to $1$.

Just by parameter counting, the probability distribution may be seen as a polynomial which live on a $2^M-1$-dimensional manifold (the normalization condition restricts this). Similarly, there are $2^M-1$ distinct moments/correlation functions $\mathbb{E}(s_1^{n_1} \cdots s_M^{n_M})$ where $n_k \in \{ 0, 1\}$ determines whether $s_k$ is in the string or not (the empty string $n_k=0$ is trivial).

Thus, it would seem clear that one should be able to reconstruct (maybe not completely or uniquely) the probability distribution $p$ given all moments $\mathbb{E}(s_1^{n_1} \cdots s_M^{n_M})$. Is this the case? If so, how could one do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use $s_0,\ldots, s_{M-1}$ rather than $s_1,\ldots, s_M$, and I'm going to let $M=\{0,1,\ldots, M-1\}$.  I'm also going to let $2=\{0,1\}$.

Knowing the probability distribution is equivalent to knowing the probabilities of all of its atoms. Each atom is uniquely represented as $$F_A=\Bigl(\bigcap_{i\in A}(s_i=1)\Bigr)\cap \Bigl(\bigcap_{i\in M\setminus A}(s_i=0)\Bigr)$$ for $A\in 2^M$.

For $A\in 2^M$, let $$X_A=\prod_{i\in A}s_i=\prod_{i\in M}s_i^{1_A(i)}.$$ Note that $X_A$ is just the indicator of $$H_A:=\Bigl(\bigcap_{i\in A}(s_i=1)\Bigr).$$  Your question amounts to finding $\mathbb{P}(F_A)$, $A\in 2^M$, as a function of the $\mathbb{E}(X_A)$, $A\in 2^M$. We can do this.

I'll prove by induction on $m$ that if $B,C\in 2^M$ are disjoint and $|C|\leqslant m$, then with $$G_{B,C}=\Bigl(\bigl(\bigcap_{i\in B}(s_i=1)\bigr)\cap \bigl(\bigcap_{i\in C}(s_i=0)\bigr)\Bigr),$$ we can express $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{E}(G_{B,C}))$ as a linear function of the $\mathbb{P}(F_A)$, $A\in 2^M$. Once we have this for all $m$, we can apply this with $B=A$ and $C=M\setminus A$ for any $A\in 2^M$, in which case $G_{A,M\setminus A}=F_A$ are just the desired atoms.

For $m=0$ (that is, $C=\varnothing$), $G_{B,\varnothing}=H_B$ and $$\mathbb{P}(G_{B,\varnothing})=\mathbb{P}(H_B)=\mathbb{E}(X_B).$$

Assume we have the result for some $m$ and $B,C\in 2^M$ are disjoint with $|C|=m+1$. Fix any $r\in C$ and let $D=C\setminus \{r\}$.   Then $G_{B,D}=G_{B\cup \{r\},D}\cup G_{B,C}$ and $G_{B\cup \{r\},D}\cap G_{B,C}=\varnothing$. That is, we take the set on which $s_i$, $i\in B$ are $1$, $s_i$, $i\in D$ are $0$, and partition it into subsets based on whether $s_r=1$ (which gives $G_{B\cup \{r\},D}$) or $s_r=0$ (which gives $G_{B,C}$).  Since $|D|=m$, by the induction hypothesis, $\mathbb{P}(G_{B,D})$ and $\mathbb{P}(G_{B\cup \{r\},D})$ are each expressible as linear functions of the $\mathbb{E}(X_A)$, $A\in 2^M$.  Therefore $$\mathbb{P}(G_{B,C})=\mathbb{P}(G_{B,D})-\mathbb{P}(G_{B\cup \{r\},D})$$ is, too.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have accepted the previous answer, which provides a rigorous proof (possibly valid even beyond the case I'm asking for), I will also add this short constructive "proof" as a simple reference.

Let us assume that $p(\{s_k\})$ can always be written as a polynomial over the $s_k$:

$$ p(\{s_k\}) = \sum_{\Lambda} \alpha_\Lambda s_{\Lambda} $$

where the sum is taken over all possible monomials $s_\Lambda = s_1^{n_1}\cdots s_M^{n_M}$ and $\alpha_\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. I now take $s_k \in \{ -1, +1 \} $ for simplicity. It is a matter of change of variable to go back to the $0,1$ case.

Here the normalization condition $\sum_{\{s_k\}} p(\{s_k\}) = 1$ imposes that the zeroth-order coefficient is $1/2^M$, while the other coefficients are irrelevant for this purpose. I now change parametrization to:

$$ p(\{s_k\}) = \frac{1}{2^M}\sum_{\Lambda} \beta_\Lambda s_{\Lambda} $$

Positivity $p(\{s_k\}) \geq 0$ then imposes that $0\leq \beta_\Lambda \leq 1$.

We now note that two distinct monomials are orthogonal under the inner product:

$$ \frac{1}{2^M} \sum_{\{s_k\}} s_\Lambda s_{\Lambda'} = \delta_{\Lambda,\Lambda'}, $$

since the product of two monomials is either another monomials (whose sum is zero) or the identity (which happens only if the two monomials are identical, since $s_k^2 = 1$).

Finally, we have that:

$$ \mathbb{E}[S_\Gamma] = \sum_{\{s_k\}} s_\Gamma p(\{s_k\}) = \sum_{\{s_k\}} s_\Gamma \frac{1}{2^M}\sum_{\Lambda} \beta_\Lambda s_{\Lambda} =\\
=  \sum_{\Lambda} \beta_\Lambda \sum_{\{s_k\}} s_\Gamma s_{\Lambda} = \sum_{\Lambda} \beta_\Lambda \delta_{\Gamma,\Lambda} = \beta_{\Gamma} $$

Consequently, we have that the correlation functions are precisely (up to normalization) the coefficients of the probability distribution seen as a polynomial, which provides the desired relation.